# Allocate resources (rows) using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm using mariadb. There is a `resource` table, with column `id`, a `used` flag and other resource descriptors. Each row represents one allocation unit of resource. I'm having trouble in allocating a row.

In each transaction, I want to:

1. Select and lock a row that is not `used`.
2. Set `used` to `true`.
3. Manipulate DB based on the selected row.
4. And then commit.

Requirements:

- There can be many concurrent transactions.
- It can select any one row that is not `used`.
- It should not block.
- In case step 3 fails, the transaction is rolled-back and restarted. It's better a different row can be selected.

First I tried `SELECT * FROM resource WHERE used=0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE`, but in concurrent case, a second transaction would block until the first one ends.

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM resource WHERE used=0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE    <-- second tx waits here until first commits
...
COMMIT
```

Then I tried adding randomness by `ORDER BY rand()`. But seems this will sort the entire table first, so still blocks.

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM resource WHERE used=0 ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE    <-- still blocks
...
COMMIT
```

Any hints?

Comment: Just checking, what table type are you using

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm using InnoDB

Comment: Ok, now show us some code that you have tried. It will help explain what you are trying to do

Comment: @RiggsFolly The real code is actually in Java, I was trying manually in mysql shell.

Comment: Edited to make more clear

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your processing will take a non-trivial amount of time, or that you have a very large number of concurrent transactions - otherwise, it's probably easier to just accept the blocking.

I have solved this in the past by having a more granular status that "used".

In pseudo code:

```
begin transaction
select the row to process, set status to "in progress", and mark with unique process identifier
end transaction

begin transaction
select the row with "in progress" and my unique process identifier
complete other processing logic
set row status to "used"
if error:
   rollback transaction
   set flag to "error"
else
  commit transaction
```

This does still block the table, but for a fraction of a second.

We had a separate job that looked for "abandoned" transactions (records with an "error" flag, and reported on those to an admin console).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But seems it does not clear the "in progress" flag when the transaction rolls-back. It may need more logic in process id management and fault handling.

Comment: I've updated the answer - though this is highly application-specific.